# scrollToItem isn't working in my CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, userdefaults

Why scrollToItem isn't working in my CollectionView? I want to work scrollToItem on `EnabledID`. So what's a problem and how fixed it?

**Code:**

```
var dataArray = NSMutableArray() // dataArray is has a data from Database
var EnabledID = Int()

EnabledID = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "EnabledID")
    
if EnabledID == 0 {
        
    EnabledID = 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "EnabledID")
        
} else {
    if EnabledID < dataArray.count {
        let index = NSIndexPath(item: EnabledID, section: 0)
        self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: index as IndexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: notice that, if you have dynamic size cells, scrolling will not work properly for some reason: http://www.openradar.me/37836568 https://github.com/airbnb/MagazineLayout/issues/68

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this code...

Objective-C

```
[collectionView setDelegate:self];
[collectionView reloadData];
[collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Swift - 4.x

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

When the scroll direction is horizontal you need to use **left**,**right** or **centeredHorizontally**.

**top** is for the vertical direction.

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: "When the scroll direction is horizontal you need to use left,right or centeredHorizontally. " - this comment just saved me an hour. Thank you so much! =D

Comment: @baskInEminence nice to hear that !!!

Answer (score 34):

the best way i found to do this is to not use scrollToItem but to get the CGRect of the index and then make that visible.

```
 let rect = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0))?.frame
 self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(rect!, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 11):

My problem is a little weird. My iPhone 6/7/8 works fine, but iPhone X or 11 cannot scroll to my expected position.
My original code is :

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 10, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

After I add collectionView.layoutIfNeeded(). Problem solves on my iPhone X and 11.

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 10, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

This answer is inspired by @ram. He should get the credit. Add this answer is just to emphasize the difference between different iPhones. So people can search their answer quicker.

Comment: collectionView.layoutIfNeeded(), this saved my time. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I use such workaround:

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
collectionView.scrollToItem(
    at: /* needed IndexPath */,
    at: .centeredHorizontally,
    animated: true
)
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

I've found such solution in several posts [here](https://akshay-s-somkuwar.medium.com/uicollectionview-scrolltoitem-issue-and-its-fix-xcode-ios-14-and-swift-a886141b459a) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663156?answerId=647268022#647268022).

Answer (score 3):

try this.it is work for me

```
func scrollToIndex(index:Int) {
     let rect = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at:IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))?.frame
     self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(rect!, animated: true)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because contentSize is probably (0,0).
If you not wish to use layoutIfNeeded() (because maybe you could be performing some undesirable an unnecessary stuff there), you should calculate it yourself (assuming your data is loaded, and the view did layout).

**Swift 5.2**

```
    collection.contentSize = CGSize(width: collection.bounds.width * CGFloat(items.count), height: collection.bounds.height)
    collection.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: startingIndex, section: 0), at: .left, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for horizontal collection view

```
var isViewDidLayoutCallFirstTime = true


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    guard self.isViewDidLayoutCallFirstTime else {return}
    self.isViewDidLayoutCallFirstTime = false
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize // It will required to re calculate collectionViewContentSize in internal method 
    let indexpath = IndexPath(item: self.currentIndex, section: 0)

    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexpath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case .centeredVertically had no effect and was failing quietly.
.centeredHorizontally fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue on iOS 14.x and Xcode 12.x.

The solution that worked for me was to use:

```
collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var scrollImg: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

   @objc func autoScroll() {
    
    let totalCount = imageArray.count-1
    
    if scrollImg == totalCount{
        scrollImg = 0
    }else {
        scrollImg += 1
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let rect = self.listOfViewsCollectionViews.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(row: self.scrollImg, section: 0))?.frame
        if self.scrollImg == 0{
            self.listOfViewsCollectionViews.scrollRectToVisible(rect!, animated: false)
        }else {
            self.listOfViewsCollectionViews.scrollRectToVisible(rect!, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to chance scrollToItem in viewDidLoad, it's won't work

do it in  viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
             collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

or

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

**Use This**

```
self.messageCV.reloadData()
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
self.messageCV.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true) // .top
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct?? Because get me warning (Value 'cell' was defined but never used; consider replacing with boolean test, Replace 'let cell  = self.myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? CollectionViewCell' with '(self.myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? CollectionViewCell) != nil').

And your condition `if let cell = self.myCollectionView...` is empty !!

Comment: use this code , because same error solution In my project

Comment: this if. condition is checking only

Comment: I checked and print in console (`not able to cast collection view cell class to CollectionViewCell`)

Comment: collection view issue in your side , outlet , add class name ,

Comment: Thank you for your suggested

Comment: after 6:30 clock to not solve error to give me team id  , I will try to solution your code

Comment: I don't have team and 6:30 the time of which city ?

Comment: OK, do u have email or any account of social network ?

Comment: Is same name in stack overflow ?

Comment: I followed you, check your account

Comment: OK, I'm waiting you